# Background color is not changing while using wordpress theme customisation api

Tags: php, css, wordpress

Here is my code in functions.php :-

```
<?php

add_theme_support('menus');

register_nav_menus(

array('primary' =>__('Primary Menu'))

);


function awesome_script_enque(){



 wp_enqueue_style('customstyle',get_template_directory_uri().'css/awesome.css',array(),'1.0.0','all');




wp_enqueue_script('customjs',get_template_directory_uri().'css/awesome.js',array(),'1.0.0',true);

}

add_action('wp_enqueue_scripts','awesome_script_enque');

function awesome_customizer_register($wp_customize){

$wp_customize->add_section('awesome_colors',array(
'title' => __('Colors','awesome'),
'description'=>'Modify the theme colour' )
);
$wp_customize->add_setting('background_color',array(
'default' => '#fff',
));

$wp_customize->add_control( new 
WP_Customize_Color_Control($wp_customize,'background_color',array(
'label' =>__('Edit Background Color','awesome') ,
'selection' =>'awesome_colors',
'settings'=>'background_color'
 )));

 }
 add_action('customize_register','awesome_customizer_register');

 function customtheme_customize_css()
 {
 ?>
 <style type="text/css">
 h1{color:<<?php echo get_theme_mod('background_color','#fff'); ?>}
</style>
<?php
}
?>
```

I referred lots of tutorial all of them had same process. Still I am not able to get customizer box named Colors in customize area where there are options like menus ,static front page etc..... Can any one point out what I am  doing wrong ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is the small mistake on your code. On the last line, you have change font color, not background and also you are not adding function via a hook. Below is the correct code:

```
function customtheme_customize_css()
{
 ?>
 <style type="text/css">
 h1{background:<?php echo get_theme_mod('background_color','#fff'); ?>}
 </style>
<?php
}
add_action( 'wp_head', 'wpdocs_style' );
```

Comment: No i tried what you said but it is not working. Since I am not getting even that option for changing color in the left panel while customisation,I think there should be problem in awesome_customizer_register function

Comment: on your code controller ID and setting ID is same I have to change the controller ID below is updated code.

$wp_customize->add_control( new 
WP_Customize_Color_Control($wp_customize,'background_color_change',array(

'label' =>__('Edit Background Color','awesome') ,

'selection' =>'awesome_colors',

'settings'=>'background_color'

 )));

Comment: Sir,I have done the changes as you said but it is still not working. I am sharing my code so that you can edit it and point out he exact problem -> https://codeshare.io/2jeqZv  and btw the add_action you have added is giving me error too.

Comment: I have done the changes in the code, now it is working for me. please check your side.

Comment: Thank you that worked but how were you be able to debug.Can you give me suggestion to master wordpress development?

Comment: I have use var_dump() for print every step.after the var_dump() write exit(); so you can see the output of each step.

Comment: I used to use var_dump while I was doing laravel development but can you please specifically show the code here https://codeshare.io/2jeqZv how to use it for wordpress development.

Comment: sir even one example will help me can show in the above link?

Comment: sure wait for 30min, I will give you an example.

Comment: before start to debug the code you need to on debug mode. open wp-config.php file and set wp_debug true.

Comment: And every time we have to var dump the parameter of the function right?